# How do you call upon an array

Tags: java, arrays

when using an array in your coding: can you call upon it by using:

This is the array itself

```
array[]= new Int[5]
```

would i call upon it with this or something else?

```
array[3]= keyb.nextInt();
```

Comment: What do you mean by call? Do you mean accessing it's index? Then yes you can do it like that. Did you try it? and yes, `Int` is no type defined in `Java`. In should be `int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"would i call upon it with this or something else?"

```
array[3]= keyb.nextInt();
```

Yes, you can do this, as long as the position you are accessing is between 0 and size of you array minus 1.

Answer (score 2):

Array declaration and creation:

```
int [] x = new int[5];
```

assignment:

```
x[3] = keyb.nextInt();
```

further readings:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

```
array[3] = keyb.nextInt();
```

This is fine. It will call `keyb.nextInt()` and assign the result to the element of `array` at index 3 (note that array indices start at zero).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you'd just access the index you want and set it.  You should probably read the [Java Arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), it'll go over the basics for you.